# Days in month as date objects

Tags: python, date

How to generate a `list` of `date` objects for each day in a specific month and year.

I've tried using `calendar` module, but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the timedelta module you can loop through all the possible values nicely and stop when the month changes.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def generate_month_days(year, month):
    start_date = date(year, month, 01)

    cur_date = start_date
    while cur_date.month == start_date.month:
        yield cur_date
        cur_date += timedelta(days=1)

for d in generate_month_days(2015,11):
    print d
```